# Using repo in Cygwin to download Android source

Tags: android, git, cygwin

Following the instructions on http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and https://honey200.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/download-android-source-code-in-windows/ I can't initialize a repo when running under Cygwin on Windows. I've done this before on Linux and everything has worked.

In the cygin terminal I've got git and curl installed, but when I run:

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.0_r7

I get the following:

```
Get https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 390, in Execute
    self._SyncManifest(opt)
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 163, in _SyncManifest
    m._InitGitDir(mirror_git=mirrored_manifest_git)
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2148, in _InitGitDir
    self.bare_objdir.init()
  File "/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2644, in runner
    p.stderr))
error.GitError: manifests init: fatal: Could not switch to '/cygdrive/e/lollipop/source/.repo/': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?